# Book recommendation on 2D Fourier Transform

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, book-recommendation, signal-processing

I have read most of "Signals and Systems" by Oppenheim and Willsky, which is a great book but it mostly focuses on 1D Fourier transform.
Could you recommend a book that has dived into 2D Fourier transforms in depth?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Oppenheim & Schafer's *Digital Signal Processing* (1975). If I properly recall, it covers 2-dimensional Fourier transforms a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Two-dimensional imaging](https://archive.org/details/twodimensionalim00rona) by Ronald N. Bracewell.

Comment: I agree, it's a great book with great illustrations.

Comment: I a completely different domain, take a look at the first volume of "The theory of Moiré phenomenon" (author : I. Amidror) which applies 2D Fourier transform to Moiré patterns.